# RestTemplate Balanced DNS Requests

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, resttemplate

Considering the following code:

```java
ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange("http://balanced.domain.com:9000/api/endpoint", HttpMethod.PUT, requestObject, String.class);
```

Where `balanced.domain.com` points to a multiple IP balanced DNS, let's say `1.1.1.1` and `2.2.2.2`.

If i execute the exchange request several times (in a loop) all the requests are sent to the same IP (let's say `1.1.1.1`) i.e. there is no balanced load between those 2 IP's.

All of this aware of that is necessary to configure a parameter in the JVM to enable the refresh of the DNS information on `$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/java.security` using `networkaddress.cache.ttl=0` (something different from -1).

The ugly solution I implemented looks something like this:

```java
InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName("balanced.domain.com");
//This gives you a different IP on several executions
String ip = address.getHostAddress();

HttpHeaders requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
requestHeaders.setAccept(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
requestHeaders.setAcceptCharset(Collections.singletonList(Charset.forName("utf-8")));
//Needed header for routing
requestHeaders.set("Host", "balanced.domain.com:9000");

HttpEntity request = new HttpEntity<>(requestObject, requestHeaders);
//Replacing domain by obtained IP
ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange("http://"+ip+":9000/api/endpoint", method, request, String.class);
```

Additionally to set the Host header the following configuration is needed `sun.net.http.allowRestrictedHeaders=true`, for example in Tomcat in `setenv.sh` would be `export CATALINA_OPTS=“$CATALINA_OPTS -Dsun.net.http.allowRestrictedHeaders=true”`.

I'm not proud on this code, so if you have a different approach that solves this problem please share it.

Comment: this looks fairly dependent on the mechanism used for load balancing.  normally a balanced endpoint would resolve to a single public ip address and then do load balancing on an internal network.  this looks like it may just be a development environment issue?

Comment: If that's true, please consider that the balancing strategy is round robin (in fact in the real case it is)